# How to set Animation Segue Style In Xib File like as StoryBoard Segue Style in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i am newbie in iOS Development i want to make an animation Style with Animation in Xib file.It is Possible?If it was Possible then please Give me Solution For that i Write a Segue For Xib like as

```
- (IBAction)pushMyNewViewController
 {
MyNewViewController *myNewVC = [[MyNewViewController alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:YES];
}
```

It is Working But i want an animation Style like as StoryBoard Segue Style Cover Vertical,Flip Horizontal,Cross Dissolve Transition Style.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Different transition on presentModalViewController:animated:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3659080/different-transition-on-presentmodalviewcontrolleranimated)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
  UIViewController *myNewVC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
myNewVC.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;

[self presentViewController:myNewVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: i want to use custom animatation

Comment: you can set custom animation class for segue